# Difference between Worksheet.Paste and Range.PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, excel

I noticed that one difference between the two is that `Worksheet.Paste` will copy objects (charts, buttons etc.) whereas `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` does not seem to do that. Are there any other differences? Is there a good explanation for the difference? So if I want to copy and paste objects/controls along with cells, do I have to do `Worksheet.Paste`? What's annoying about that is that you would then have to activate that sheet and select the destination cell. Or is there a better approach? Thanks!

Comment: ```Range-Paste-Special``` pastes a range from the Clipboard into the specified range. ```Worksheet-Paste``` pastes the contents of the Clipboard onto the sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manipulate any object in Excel (chart, shape, controls etc.).
It is advisable to always work directly on the object. Consider below.

```
Dim sh As Shape
Set sh = Sheet1.Shapes("Oval 1") 

sh.Copy
With Sheet2
    .Paste .Range("A1")
End With
```

In above sample, you want to copy the *Shape - Oval 1* in Sheet1 to Sheet2 cell A1.
So what we did is we get hold of the *Shape* object and use its method to execute what we want.

So let `Range.PasteSpecial` serve its purpose as method of Range Object and let other objects do the same like we what did above where we don't really need to use *Select or Activate*. In short work with objects separately using it's available *properties and methods*.